# Rotate cursor with jquery, possible?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to rotate the cursor image in jquery on click?

```
$(".fullWidth").css('cursor','url(http://w17.snunit.k12.il/images/big_arrow.png),auto').rotate(90);
```

On click I would like this cursor image to rotate 45 degrees. Imagine having a "+" on rollover but once you click the "+" cursor image can transform into an "x". Basically I'd like to toggle between the two.

Comment: I would do it by adding/removing a class that rotates it with a css transition.

Comment: well, the class part is simple. `$(".fullWidth").toggleClass("rotate")` As far as the rotate/css transitions, i'd have to google them, you mightaswell too. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: So you want the animation and not just the rotation yea? Otherwise you could just change the img source to switch to a rotated version.

Comment: This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve (the image rollovers) http://www.beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayH6#up-close

Comment: You can do this with CSS sprites without ever having to use Jquery(accept for click actions I guess).